# Can the eclipse ide invoke cmake, with different options, from within the IDE when the configuration is changed?

Tags: cmake, eclipse-cdt

I have been trying to get this question answered for several years and people keep answering slightly different questions.

I have a working cmake with CMakeLists.txt.
It supports both Debug and Release versions
It builds in successfully in eclipse

Currently, I must go to a terminal, in the eclipse project dir, and type

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug CMakeLists.txt

to switch from Release to Debug.

Inside the eclipse IDE, I can set up Debug and Release configurations - BUT when I switch between them, it DOES NOT RUN cmake to build the appropriate make files automatically.

The question:

Is the eclipse ide *capable* of invoking cmake with the appropriate options when the configuration is changed?

I suspect the answer is no. If so, please state that outright. I am not seeking alternate solutions or workarounds - because I already have them. I want to know if I should stop a treasure hunt for something that does not exist.

If the answer is yes, how do I set that up?